# How to insert in WebSQL / Phonegap SQLite with auto increment?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, web-sql

I'm working on a small Phonegap Project, and have problems with finding the right syntax to insert into a WebSQL database. I'm reading a jSON response from an API and try to cache it to a WebSQL / SQLite database but always get an error message. The database is created, the table also... problem is the insert.
For inserting the different Rows into the database I iterate over my JSON. All variables are set and shown when I display them with console.log. What am I doing wrong?

songdata = JSON.parse(songdata);
// JSON Gespielte Songs für ALLE Clubs abfragen, in SQLite speichern, und bei "success" weiter an den clubboxstyler weiterleiten

```
        db = window.openDatabase("database.db", "1.0", "Demo", -1);
        db.transaction(function(tx){
             tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS activity_stream (id integer primary key autoincrement, band text, clubID integer, time text, title text)');
             for (var kay in songdata) 
                {
                var Xband = songdata[kay].band;
                var XclubID = songdata[kay].clubID;
                var Xtime = songdata[kay].time;
                var Xtitle = songdata[kay].title;
                console.log(Xtitle);
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO activity_stream (id, band, clubID, time, title) VALUES (1, ?, ?, ?, ?), [1, Xband, XclubID, Xtime, Xtitle]');
                }

        }, function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
        });
```

Thank you for you help! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in your code snippet you are explicitly setting the same id (that equals '1') to each row you are inserting. That can't work, as primary keys need to differ, right? :)

The thing with autoincrementing columns is that you don't provide value for them, they are set up for you automatically. So just omit the 'id' column when inserting, like this:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO activity_stream (band, clubID, time, title) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?), [Xband, XclubID, Xtime, Xtitle]');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot molderek - additionally I had a stupid syntax error. `tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO activity_stream (band, clubID, time, title) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', [Xband, XclubID, Xtime, Xtitle]);`